# Pasar información de un UIViewController a otro documento

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4

Me gustaría saber cual es la manera *más eficiente* de pasar información de un archivo **Swift** a otro por ejemplo de un *ViewController* a el *modelo de datos* o a otro *View* que nos interese, gracias de antemano.

```
UIViewController1
```

Aqui un primer archivo

```
func prueba() -> String{
        return "ejemplo"}
```

Con esta función y luego otro archivo que recibe los datos por ejemplo

```
UIVewController2
```

¿Como podría recuperar los datos?

```
print(UIViewcontroller.prueba)
```

Aqui me da error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de presentar otro view Controller, debes añadir:

```
nextViewController.name = yourTextField.text
```

Claro, deberás tener declarada la variable 'name' en tu NextViewController.

Imaginemos que pulsamos un botón y queremos pasar cierta información al siguiente View Controller:

```
@IBAction func doSegue(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let resultVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResultViewController")as! ResultViewController

        // you can set any value stored in the destination VC here
        resultVC.name = "Ejemplo"
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(resultVC, animated: true)
    }
```

Volviendo a tu caso, estás intentando llamar una función en otro View Controller. Esto da un problema basicamente porque estás intentado acceder a algo que no puedes (echale un ojo a las instancias y constructores). Si quieres llamar a ese metodo desde otro view controller, declara la función `prueba()` como `static`

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar de un view controller a otro puedes relacionarlos mediante un segue way, de esta manera puedes pasar información de un view controller a otro.

Digamos que tienes un MyViewController1 y quieres pasar información a MyViewController2

```
class MyViewController1: UIViewController {

    var infoPrueba: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Asignamos algún valor a la variable que deseamos
        infoPrueba = "Esta es una info"
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue" {
            //Obtenemos la referencia del siguiente view controller
            let controller2 = segue.destination as! MyViewController2
            //Aqui pasas la variable de información al siguiente view controller
            controller2.infoDeViewController1 = infoPrueba
        }
    }
}

class MyViewController2: UIViewController {

    var infoDeViewController1: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         //En este punto la variable debe contener la información del 
         anterior view controller
         print(infoDeViewController1)
    }
}
```